# ruby in-memory object database with unlimited instances

Tags: ruby, sequel, in-memory-database

I'm trying to get a sort of object database in memory which can support an arbitrary number of instances/connections. Lets start with the library example:

Lets say I have a `Library` class. I can create as many instances of this class as I want.
Each instance of `Library` has a collection of `Library::Book` objects (accessible as `library.books`). This collection of books is specific to that library instance.
I also have `Library::Magazine` which behaves the same.
And with this I can do things like `library.books['Nineteen Eighty Four'].author`, `library.magazines.each {...}`, `library.magazines.delete(magazine)`.

Now up to this point it isn't hard. Any database model library can handle it. However I want to be able to clone the "library". Meaning I can take an instance of `Library`, and do `library.clone`, and get a brand new library which is an exact duplicate of the origin. But the new copy will have it's own collection of `Books` and `Magazines` (which was created from the origin).
This means it should create a duplicate database, and both databases can be accessed simultaneously.

It's this arbitrary number of databases with simultaneous access that seems to be very difficult. Ideally I would like it to be a relational database with foreign key constraints (so I can do something like `library.categories['fiction'].books.each {...}` and have a foreign key on the book referencing the category it's in).

I've been hacking away with [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) for a bit, and it comes close in that it allows multiple sqlite in-memory databases. But it's proving extremely difficult to get it to support an arbitrary number of them (it wants a constant class representing each table in each database).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all databases have the same schema, you may be able to use Sequel's sharding support (http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sharding_rdoc.html) and a single model class per table (instead of a model class per table per database).  You can use Database#add_servers and Database#remove_servers to adjust the available shards at runtime.